# Cleanly unload shared library and start over with Python CFFI

Tags: python, python-cffi

I'm setting up and opening a DLL like this:

```
from cffi import FFI
ffi = FFI()

api_path = '/path_to/api.h'
lib_path = '/path_to/lib.so'
with open(api_path) as f:
   ffi.cdef(f.read())
mylib = ffi.dlopen(lib_path)

myfunc_c = ff.callback('int (char *)', myfunc)
#etc...
```

How can I close the library and open it again? If I do

```
del mylib
```

and try the above code again I get `CDefError: cannot parse ...` when
attempting `ffi.cdef()`.

I've seen some examples for ctypes using `dlclose()` but can't find an equivalent for CFFI.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, CFFI has no way to call explicitly the C-level `dlclose()`.  It is only called implicitly if the library object goes out of scope.  Also, the `ffi` object keeps this library alive, so `ffi` needs to go out of scope too.

If you really want to do it, you need to make sure all references to `mylib` and `ffi` are gone, and call `gc.collect()`.  (If you want then to reload, you need to start again with a fresh `ffi = FFI()`.)

The next version of CFFI might add something like `ffi.close_libraries()` that unloads the libraries loaded in this `ffi` object.

**EDIT:** it won't work for libraries loaded with `verify()` on CPython, because these ones are regular CPython C extension modules, and CPython never unloads its C extension modules.  This means that the general `ffi.close_libraries()` idea might be doomed...

Answer (score 1):

`dlclose(lib)` exists, but only for the  out-of-line/precompiled FFIs.

http://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cdef.html#ffi-dlopen-loading-libraries-in-abi-mode